# Sequence limit and monotony of $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{4a_n+3},a_1=5$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having difficulty proving whether the sequence is increasing or decreasing and finding its limit. Using derivative I find that it is increasing, but there seems to be another way. Computing $a_{n+1}-a_n$ gets messy for me.
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{4a_n+3},a_1=5$$

Comment: It seems hard for it to be increasing, since $a_2=\sqrt{23}<a_1$. Do you mean eventually increasing? That seems unlikely, too.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed. A quick check with matlab showed this sequence decreases toward $a_* \simeq 4.6458$ pretty rapidly.

Comment: You can solve for $a_*$ explicitly: if $a_n \to a_*$, then $a_* = \sqrt{4a_* + 3}$ so $a_*^2 = 4a_* + 3$ and so $a_* = 2 \pm \sqrt 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove by induction to show that the sequence $\{a_n \}$ is decreasing.

For $n=1$, we have $$a_2=\sqrt{4a_1+3}=\sqrt{4(5)+3}=\sqrt{23}<\sqrt{25}=5=a_1,$$ or $a_1>a_2.$

For $n=k$, assume that the statement $$a_k>a_{k+1} \tag{$\star$}$$ is true. Now, multiplying both sides by $4$, then adding $3$ to both sides, then applying the square root to both sides of $(\star)$ gives $$\sqrt{4a_k+3}>\sqrt{4a_{k+1}+3}.$$ This means $$a_{k+1}>a_{k+2}.$$

and hence the sequence is decreasing.

---

Now, to find the limit, set $a=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$. Then $a=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}$ as well. Thus,

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{4a_n+3}
\end{align}
becomes
\begin{align}
a= \sqrt{4a+3}.
\end{align}
Now solve for $a$ and you will find your limit.

Comment: this is nice idea, I have used it at past but forgot it. After proving that it is decreasing how to prove that it converges ?

Comment: After proving that it is decreasing, you can then prove also by induction that the sequence is also bounded. Then use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to conclude that the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Upper bound is $a_1=5$ but for lower bound which one should I take ? I used $4a_n+3>0$ ... Any tip for an alternative way ?

Comment: The easiest lower bound to work with is 0. Don't forget that you're not looking for the best lower bound, but for a lower bound.

Comment: @Parhs You can use the limit of the sequence you found to be the lower bound of your decreasing sequence. Show that $a_n$ is greater than that limit for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess my poor way I mentioned before $an>-3/4$ is correct too ?

Comment: If you solve $a=\sqrt{4a+3}$ (which can be arranged to become a quadratic equation $a^2-4a-3=0$), you will get $a=1$ or $a=3$. Either bound works here (and you can prove either of them by induction), but it is usually not the case for most recursive sequences. For example, consider the sequence $\{s_n\}$ with $s_1=7$ and $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{s_n+6}$. If we set $s=\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$, we obtain $$s=\sqrt{s+6} \implies s^2-s-6=0 \implies s=3,s=-2.$$ But all the terms of $s_n$ are positive, since $s_1$ is positive and $s_{n+1}$ involves a square root. And a square root is never a negative number.

Comment: Anyways, for your sequence, prove by induction that $a_n > 3$ for all natural numbers $n$. (Assume that $a_n>3$ is true; show that $a_{n+1}>3$.) You can also do this for $a_n > 1$ since $1$ is nonnegative and $a_n > 3 > 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to prove that the series is monotonic.

If you assume that the series converges you can use a quite common trick to find the limit. Say the limit exists and it's equal to $L$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L$$

Intuitively you know that the limit for $a_n$ and for $a_{n+1}$ should be the same so you can write something like

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{4a_n+3}$$

Now, as the limit for $a_n$ exists you can use some property of limits of functions to get to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{4a_n+3}= \sqrt{4\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n+3}=\sqrt{4L+3}$$

So you end up with

$$L=\sqrt{4L+2}$$

That gives you two solutions for $L$, $2+\sqrt{7}$ and $2-\sqrt{7}$. Now, as you know the series is all positives (because square roots are always positive numbers) then you can discard the negative solution and get

$$L=2+\sqrt{7}$$

Comment: But he must prove that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges. In fact by finding the number $L$ and since $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing he can prove that $a_n<L$.

Comment: I know this trick but I have to show the monotonicity first and an is decreasing..

Comment: @Parhs You don't need to know the sequence to use the trick. Knowing what the limit must be can occasionally help in showing the sequence is monotonic or in identifying an explicit formula for the terms of the sequence. See e.g. abel's answer

Answer (score 1):

the sequence $\{a_n \}$ is decreasing and converges to $2 + \sqrt 7$

we also have $$(a_{n+1} - 2 - \sqrt 7) = 
\dfrac{4(a_n - 2 - \sqrt 7)}{\sqrt{4a_n + 3} + 2 + \sqrt 7}<\dfrac{4}{2+\sqrt 7}(a_n-2-\sqrt 7)$$ which guarantees the convergence and monotonicity of $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_{n-1}<a_n$ then $\sqrt{4a_{n-1}+3}<\sqrt{4a_n+3}$, so $a_n<a_{n+1}$.